# The requested resource is not available for servlet 3.0 and tomcat 7.0

Tags: java

My dynamic web module version is 3.0 and tomcat my tomcat version is `7.0`.

I don't know why it can't see my servlet XD when I navigate to the page **localhost:8080/SimpleProject**.

When I navigate to **localhost:8080/SimpleProject/firstservlet**, I get the error message that says  `the requested resource is not available!`

Here's my servlet:

```
@WebServlet(description = "the first servlet", urlPatterns = { "/firstservlet" })
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//   response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("<h1>Why can't See<h1>");
}
```

I didn't do anything on my web.xml because what I know is in 3.0 version the url mapping is in the servlet.

[image]

this is my file arrangement :)
[image]

Comment: Your context (root path) is your war name (complete with ".war") unless you specifically set it to something else in your context.xml file.

Comment: can you share you web.xml ?

Comment: @ShadowCreeper i already did that. still The requested resource is not available

Comment: @F.H. and when you put a html file in the root of your war, can you hit that with your browser? `http://localhost:8080/SimpleProject/index.html` for instance?

Comment: @ShadowCreeper yeah i did that...

Comment: @F.H. are we to infer that this means you can reach the index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the log files to see if some exception is being thrown when loading/executing your servlet FirstServlet?

Did you check the content of your war file to make sure it is packaged properly and the servlet class is in it (you can open a war file like you would a zip file).